# Bad flag in substitue

Tags: regex, linux, sed, scripting

I'm getting the following:
sed: 1: "s/^PATH=.*/PATH=/bin:/s ...": bad flag in substitute command: 'b'
what's wrong with my sed?

```
sed -i '' "s/^PATH=.*/PATH="\/bin:\/sbin:\/usr\/bin:\/usr\/sbin:\/usr\/local\/bin:\/Users\/jd\/bin:\/opt\/local\/bin:\/usr\/local\/bin/\" ~/.bash_profile
```

I'm unable to figure out my mistake .
I'd appreciate some help. 
Thanks.

BTW I'm running MacOS if it makes any difference.

Comment: You escaped the last quote. Wrap the pattern with single quotes, see https://ideone.com/Tr1AWK

Comment: also, avoid [Leaning toothpick syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome) by choosing a different delimiter

Answer (score 0):

replace `"` to `'` and remove last `\`:

```
sed -i '' 's/^PATH=.*/PATH="\/bin:\/sbin:\/usr\/bin:\/usr\/sbin:\/usr\/local\/bin:\/Users\/jd\/bin:\/opt\/local\/bin:\/usr\/local\/bin/' ~/.bash_profile
```